# Scala for expressions in tail recursive form

Tags: scala, tail-recursion, for-comprehension

I have a bit of a problem trying to come up with a valid way to convert a for - expression N queens solution to a tail recursive form and still preserve the idiomatic nature achieved by using the for syntax. Any ideas are more than welcome.

```
def place(boardSize: Int, n: Int): Solutions = n match {
  case 0 => List(Nil)
  case _ =>
    for {
      queens <- place(boardSize, n - 1)
      y <- 1 to boardSize
      queen = (n, y)
      if (isSafe(queen, queens))
    } yield queen :: queens
}

def isSafe(queen: Queen, others: List[Queen]) = {...}
```

Comment: I think a backtracking solution like this is inherently non tail recursive. Unless you manage the stack yourself but then the code will evidently become less elegant.

Comment: @Jasper-M I agree that managing the stack is an obligation if we're going to make this tail-recursive without an external mutable `var`. While it does become a bit more complex, it's not that ugly either.

Answer (score 1):

What you're writing basically corresponds to what's called Depth-First Search (DFS).

Although a recursive implementation of DFS is easily written, it is not tail-recursive. Here's a proposal for a tail-recursive one. Note that I did *not* test this code, but it should at least give you an idea of how to proceed.

```
def solve(): List[List[Int]] = {
  @tailrec def solver(fringe: List[List[Int]], solutions: List[List[Int]]): List[List[Int]] = fringe match {
    case Nil => solutions
    case potentialSol :: fringeTail =>
      if(potentialSol.length == n) // We found a solution
        solver(fringe.tail, potentialSol.reverse :: solutions)
      else { // Keep looking
        val unused = (1 to n).toList filterNot potentialSol.contains
        val children = for(u <- unused ; partial = u :: fringe.head if isValid(partial)) yield partial
        solver(children ++ fringe.tail, solutions)
      }
  }
  solver((1 to n).toList.map(List(_)), Nil).map(_.reverse)
}
```

If you're concerned about performances, note that this solution is *very poor* because it uses slow operations on immutable data structure, and because on the JVM you're better off using iteration where performance matters. This will start failing quite rapidly as n increases. Algorithmically, there are far better ways to solve NQueens than using DFS.

Comment: As a matter of fact i am quite concerned about performance. Would there be a much better way that still uses immutable structures. Also, your solution is tailrecursive, so woudlnt that mean that it actually directly translates to an itterative one by the compiler.

Comment: Since the method is marked tail-rec the compiler should indeed be able to optimise it. You will however not get the same performances as if using mutable collections. For example, you could maintain the fringe as a single `mutable.Stack` which would save you some operations. As `n` grows, even concatenating two lists like `children ++ fringe.tail` becomes uselessly costly.

Comment: While still using DFS, there are also techniques to traverse the DFS "tree" while avoiding to recompute things such as `unused` at every node. Instead you maintain a reversible set of the used values which gets automatically updated when backtracking. But that is again using non-immutable data structures. If you're interested in that kind of approach, you should check out constraint programming, which is a clever way of solving many combinatorial optimisation problems.